# How to share library within other library nx (nrwl) - singlerepo

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

*Folder structure:*

```
--shared
  ---components
  ---states
  ---api-interfaces
```

I would like to use `@lib/api-interfaces` within states and components instead:
relative path: `../../../foo/xxx/bar/{...}.ts`;.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding the path to your `tsconfig.json` located at the root of the project.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@lib/api-interfaces": ["/path/to/shared/api-interfaces.ts"],
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: The one at the root

Answer (score 1):

```
ng g @nrwl/workspace:lib api-interfaces
```

This way the lib is configured in the tsconfig, nx.json, angular.json and you don't have to manually add it.
Caution, this may remove any existing code so backup first.

Comment: That way it's not possible to use wihtin other libs it's only within other applications

Comment: You can use libs in libs..?